# dc.js - Is it possible to load a large dataset using Database

Tags: javascript, database, oracle, d3.js, dc.js

My team and I are planning to create a data visualization dashboard using dc.js. I'm not sure what limitation does the library have but we want to use Oracle database instead of using CSV file. Obviously, we'll be using JAVA as for our business side. In the database, the data will contains 3 million or more rows so its a huge data. We want to use row charts, bar charts, etc. using dc.js and crossfilters all. All the 3 million plus data will be implement in the dc.js dashboard. Is this possible? or using dc.js is not the solution? Can DC.js handle this amount of data?

I have used dc.js with all my other projects. Though I use a CSV file to load the data. First time using database approach.

Comment: Typically you will create a restful server which queries your database and returns CSV or JSON data. You wouldn't want to open up your database for anyone to access directly from the browser anyway. 3 million rows is probably too big for dc.js - rule of thumb is 0.5 - 1 million rows is okay for crossfilter as long as the aggregations bring the number of drawn elements in the charts down to thousands of elements.

Comment: If it's possible then I'd recommend pre-aggregating your data, for example take all combinations of all keys and then just count or sum the data within those combinations. Otherwise you might be stuck with some kind of server-side solution, replacing crossfilter with something on the server side - that takes some engineering.